# Crystal Reports parameter drop down list issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Hi everyone I use Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 with obviously Visual Studio.

I have created a crystal report with a parameter Employee. This is a drop down list of Employee last names that the user chooses from. The problem is that it only shows one option, which is empty space (2 options if you count the nothing option that is the three dots(...)).

The thing is before I inserted some new data this worked fine. But now there is around 2500 rows and each can have an employee attached to it although most don't.

On the other hand my other drop down list that uses the same SQL and is created in exactly the same way works fine.

I have no idea what could be causing this. I thought it was the sql but I put the Name Of Employee the same thing the DropDownList should be picking up into this other report (this is a date report showing everything between 2 dates) and it shows up fine. Again, same sql select function for filling the report.

Is it the fact that there are so many rows and so many possible employees that is causing this?

I've tried everything but it's like its only giving me the first option (the blank) in the drop down list.

When Debugging I can see that the observable collection has picked up the Last Name of the employee and can read it but for some reason in the prompt drop down list all I see is the blank option.

Here is the formula I use in CR:

{Inventar_Model_ReportClass.ImeZaduzioca} = {?Zaduzio}

It might have something to do with Crystal Reports limiting its query to the first 1000 rows

http://crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=8029

I tried setting creating MaxRowRecords here

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Suite 12.0\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV

and setting it to 5000 but still no luck

I say this because
I checked the sql and it returns the values fine, I tried deleting the report and then recreating it, same problem, I tried creating other parameters and they are all not working properly, for example I have a parameter for store, and it only shows me 97 options but when I use Count Distinct I get 140 values.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
http://scn.sap.com/thread/3195520

I was changing the wrong registry key. It has to do with what version Windows you use, 32 bit or 64. Anyway here is the right one:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\SAP BusinessObjects\Suite XI 4.0\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? 32-bit or 64-bit? 64-bit I assume?